# Calling API in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

```
//Store
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { currencyListSlice } from "./Reducers/CurrencyListReducer";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        currencyList: currencyListSlice.reducer,
    }
}
)

export default store

//CurrencyListReducer

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

export const loadCurrencyList = () => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const data = await fetch(API-Key)
        const payload = await data.json()
        
        dispatch({
            type: 'currencyList/setCurrencyList',
            payload: payload
        })
    }
}

const options = {
    name: 'currencyList',
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        setCurrencyList(state, action) {
            return action.payload
        }
    }
}

export const currencyListSlice = createSlice(options)

//CurrencyList Component

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { currencyListSlice } from '../../Reducers/CurrencyListReducer'

const selectCurrencyList = state => state.CurrencyList

export const CurrencyList = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const currencyList = useSelector(selectCurrencyList)

    const { loadCurrencyList } = currencyListSlice.actions

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(loadCurrencyList())
    }, [dispatch, loadCurrencyList])

    console.log(currencyList)

    return (
        <div>
            /*Some elements here*/
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm working with redux for the first time and having some real problem in calling API and storing data in store. The problem is I'm not getting anything from API but the `console.log(currencyList)` just gives me `undefined`. I tried calling API directly in reducer but that too didn't work out. I'm a newbie to redux and calling the API in redux is being a difficult task for me. Forgive any silly mistake(if present).

Answer (score 0):

try reading this: [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)